# python3 telnet occur cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have some question related to telnet in python3. It will occur 
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object. 
Do anyone know how to solve this issue? If use python2 will not have problem.

## The code is  just telnet to cisco server and print the mac's ipv6 address.

```
def Telnet_Check_reachability(ip):
ping_count=3
process = subprocess.Popen(['ping', ip, '-n', str(ping_count)],
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

process.wait()
stdout = process.stdout.read()
#print stdout
if "TTL=" in stdout:
    #print "Server reachable"
    successful = 1
else:
    #print "Server unreachable"
    successful = 0
return successful

def telnet_To_CMTS(Client_IP, Client_Name, Client_Pwd, MAC):
    tn =Login_Telnet(Client_IP, Client_Name, Client_Pwd)
    if "telnetlib" in str(tn):
        time.sleep(1)
        value = tn.read_until(b"Router#")
        command = "scm " + MAC + " ipv6\n"
        tn.write(command.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        #tn.write(command)

        value = tn.read_until(b"Router#")
        #print value
        tn.close()
        time.sleep(1)

        info = "2001"

        #value=str(value)

        matchObj = re.match(r'.*'+ info + '(.*)\n',value, re.M|re.DOTALL)

        if matchObj:
            Ipv6_address = info + matchObj.group(1)
            Ipv6 = Ipv6_address.replace("\n", "")
            return Ipv6
        else:
           print ("No match!!")    


    else:
        print ("Telnet failed")


ip ="192.168.1.252"
username = "guest"
password = "guest"
mac = "xxxx.bbbb.cccc"
new_IPv6 = telnet_To_CMTS(ip, username, password, mac)
#print (new_IPv6)
```

Comment: Can you add entire trackback?

Comment: File "telnet_CMTS2.py", line 16, in Telnet_Check_reachability
    if "TTL=" in stdout:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The telnet instance's [read_until](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until) method returns `bytes`, not `str`, so you need to decode `value` before passing it to the regex:

```
    value_bytes = tn.read_until(b"Router#")

    # Decode value_bytes to str.  The encoding is *probably* ASCII
    value = value_bytes.decode('ascii')

    tn.close()
    time.sleep(1)

    info = "2001"

    matchObj = re.match(r'.*'+ info + '(.*)\n',value, re.M|re.DOTALL)
```

Alternatively, you could leave `value` as `bytes` and encode `info` and the regex pattern as `bytes` instead, but it's usual to convert `bytes` to `str` and vice-versa at the boundaries of your application, unless you are working purely with `bytes`.

Comment: i have update Telnet_Check_reachability this function. i think it might be the process is in byte. Need to convert to str. Do you know how to convert? i try with stdout= stdout.decode("UTF-8"), but still not work, and it occur error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 22:

Answer (score 0):

After using value=value.decode('utf8') it can work now.

```
value = tn.read_until(b"Router#")
    #print value
    tn.close()
    time.sleep(1)

    info = "2001"

    #value=str(value)
    value=value.decode('utf8')
    matchObj = re.match(r'.*'+ info + '(.*)\n',value, re.M|re.DOTALL)
```